# SDL2 / wxWidgets SDL_CreateWindowFrom

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, sdl-2

I have spent the last few days trying to embed an SDL2 display into wxWidgets but failing miserably. OK, here is what I have so far...

First a little detail:

- wxWidgets version: 3.1 | SDL version 2.0.4 | OS: Fedora 23 | g++ 5.3.1

I have searched Google but cannot find much up-to-date information. What I have found suggests that I should use SDL_CreateWindowFrom() and then link it to a wxPanel or wxStaticBitmap.

I have written test code which implements a simple wxFrame and initialises SDL2, the code compiles fine but hangs when run.I am new to SDL2 and so would be grateful if somebody would take a look at my code and see what I am doing wrong. I'm obviously misunderstanding something here so any help would be appreciated.

The following code is a simplified block which highlights my problem.

**main.h**

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class TestApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
 wxIMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(TestApp);

// Initialise SDL before WX-Widgets and GTK3

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialise SDL and Error Check
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "SDL Initialisation Error\n\n";
    }

    return wxEntry(argc, argv);
}

// WX-WIDGETS ENTRY POINT: Handover control to WX-Widgets

bool TestApp::OnInit()
{
    UI_Frame *frame = new UI_Frame("SDL Playing with wxWidgets");
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

**TestApp.h**

```
class UI_Frame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    UI_Frame(const wxString& title);

private:

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
```

And finally, the method which handles SDL and wxFrame

**TestApp.cpp**

```
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(UI_Frame, wxFrame)

wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


UI_Frame::UI_Frame(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{

    this->SetSize(1024, 768);

    wxBoxSizer* topSizer;

    topSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL);
    topSizer->Add(panel, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);


    /*******************************************************
     *
     * SDL Specific Stuff
     *
     ******************************************************/

    SDL_Window *sdl_window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = nullptr;

    // SDL: Create Embedded Window in wxWidgets
    sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindowFrom((void *) panel->GetHandle());


    if (sdl_window == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "SDL NULL Pointer ERROR";
        return;
    }


    // *** This line causes the application to hang ***
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdl_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    if (renderer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL: failed to create renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
}
```

Comment: have the same problem with SDL-Qt integration, googled a lot, there are similar questions all over the web and no answers since 2015